# What is the regex code for meta description

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a regex code for a meta description tag.

```
#<meta|name="description|".*content|="([^"]+)"># <-
```

That is what I have, but it doesn't match capital letters, as I discovered some tags are like `META DESCRIPTION =`, etc.

Is there a new code or a way to change this one to match capital letter content?

Comment: That regex doesn't match how you think it does. The problem here is not about capital letters. For example, it would also match the string "foocontent"

Comment: the problem with your regex (not counting that it has bunch of `OR` in it) is that meta doesn't always have to be formatted this way... can have spaces, line breaks, different quotes... if it's for scrapping purposes, I would suggest to gather all meta tags and then process it - like this: `~<meta[^>]+>~is`

Answer (score 1):

Add flag `i` after your last `#`.

Like this:

```
#<meta|name="description|".*content|="([^"]+)">#i
```

That will tell your regular expression to be case insensitive. Read more about flags [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml).

Comment: I don't know. This seems to be wrong. I mean why would we search for `<meta` or `name...` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `<meta|name="description|".*content|="([^"]+)">` is broken, it means:

- `<meta`
  **OR**
- `name="description`
  **OR**
- `"` followed by anything followed by `content`
  **OR**
- `="` followed by at least one character that is not `"` followed by `">`

### Warning!

Let me say that [parsing HTML with regular expressions is a very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1184510).

### Regex alternative for training purposes

But if you want to try something out for training, start improving this:

`#<meta name="description" content="([^"]+)">#i`

which is case-insensitive and does what you think it does.

### False negatives

Beware that it won't match valid elements like this:

```
<meta name="description"      content="foo bar baz">
```

or

```
<meta
   name="description"
   content="foo bar baz">
```

or

```
<meta content="foo bar baz" name="description">
```

Comment: Well, at least the problem with the whitespaces could be alleviate, by replacing all space character with `\s+`. Otherwise, pretty good answer!

Comment: and what if it's `<meta name='description' ...>` ? or even `<meta name=description ...>` (that is a correct html syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
/<meta[^>]*name=[\"|\']description[\"|\'][^>]*content=[\"]([^\"]*)[\"][^>]*>/i
```

works for compressed html code too.

Comment: You may want to account for the fact that either a double or single quote could follow `content=` so the regex would become  `/<meta[^>]*name=[\"\']description[\"\'][^>]*content=[\"\'](.*?)[\"\'][^>]*>/i`

Answer (score 1):

Check this [php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) to get all meta details including description easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta\s+(?=[^>]*name\s*=\s*("|')description\1)[^>]*content\s*=\s*("|')(.*?)\2[^>]*>
```

Comment: Hi,
maybe you can add a small explanation to improve your answer.